# How to carry fragment transaction while showing and retaining a dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dialog

My activity should show a custom dialog with some options and depending upon options should commit a layout change without dismissing the dialog. Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: I meant not to show a dialog, but to continue showing it while committing a layout change

Answer (score 0):

> try this,
>   First make`custom.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cat" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Hey there i am cat"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

> then in activity_main.xml add following code,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />`</RelativeLayout>`
```

> then in MainActivity.java,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
B.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        d.setTitle("This is custom dialog box");
        d.show();           
    }
});
}
```

> thats it...

Comment: I meant not to show a dialog, but to continue showing it while committing a layout change